# How to measure time of a key is pressed in c#

Tags: c#

In the TextEdit a user types a word 'hello', i want to now how much time did he taked to write the word 'hello'.If possible i want to know how much time did he taked to type each character. For example the person taked 3 seconds to type the word hello, and it took him 1s to type 'h' and 2s to press 'e'.

-Thanks

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? When you say "the textedit" do you mean that you have a textbox control, or are you referring to a third-party text editor?

Comment: `Stopwatch` would be more appropriate than `timer` but your timings won't account for any time away from the screen the user takes as well as any computation time on your end.

Comment: Add a handle for `KeyDown`, `KeyPress` and/or `KeyUp` (depending on how you want to time this). Record the time when the first key is pressed in a variable. When the last key is pressed (however you determine that) compare the current time to the time you saved when the first key was pressed.

Comment: i am using textbox control

Comment: What do you want to measure? The time between the user pushing down on the "h" key and the user releasing the "o" key? The time between the user pushing down on the "h" key and the user releasing the "h" key? The time between the user pushing down on the "h" key and the user pressing down on the "e" key? The time between the user releasing the h key and pressing down on the "e" key? Suppose the user presses another key in-between, what should happen then?

Comment: I want to start measuring time when the user presses the key "h" and stop the time when the user releases the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If talking about Windows Forms, you can use `Control.Leave` and `Control.Enter` events. Something like this.

And you can use `TextChanged` to see how long it takes for the text to be changed.

```
DateTime StartTime;
DateTime EndTime;

private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Entered");
    StartTime = DateTime.Now;
}

private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Left");
    EndTime = DateTime.Now;
    MessageBox.Show("Time in control: " + EndTime.Subtract(StartTime).ToString());
}
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Changed at : " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(StartTime).ToString());
    StartTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```